# Laser spot size with pinhole

Tags: optics, laser, geometric-optics, spectroscopy

I am currently trying to find the focus of an IR laser beam by using a 300 $\mu$m pinhole. Now, when I am scanning the pinhole across the beam and plotting the pinhole position vs the laser spectrum amplitude at a given wavelength, on both $x$ and $y$ axes I obtain a profile which is well fit by a Gaussian whose width, depending on the $z$ position, ranges from 150 to 200 $\mu$m.

I cannot get my head around what I am observing, if what I am measuring was the beam waist, given my pinhole is way bigger than the Gaussian width retrieved by the fit, I should observe a plateau when I am scanning the pinhole across the beam, and not a Gaussian with a well defined maximum. Also, the spectrum I measure with the pinhole in the beam is less intense then without pinhole in, so I am assuming I am clipping some of it.

What could be the source of such underestimation of the laser beam radius?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The beam does not end at the beam diameter. A significant portion of the beam is outside it.

By convention, the beam diamenter is the diameter where the field is $1/e$ of the central value, or the intensity is $1/e^2$ of the central value.

Comment: I do agree with that, but I don't see how this should answer my question

Comment: A 300 $\mu m$ pinhole is not way bigger than a 200 $\mu m$ beam waist. You should not expect a plateau.